# MAC go get github.com/go-gl/gl

Tags: macos, go

On MAC i am trying to setup GO-GL, but when i run

```
go get github.com/go-gl/gl
```

I get the following error:

```
In file included from src/github.com/go-gl/gl/attriblocation.go:7:./gl.h:2:10: fatal error: 'GL/glew.h' file not found
```

Someone please help me figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a good reason not to, you should use go-gl/glow package instead of go-gl/gl. It will provide you and your users with a better experience.

https://github.com/go-gl/glow#glow